# Argument of type 'RefObject<HTMLDivElement>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IDivPosition'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am using Typescript with react. I create a separate file for my custom function as `DivPosition.tsx`

I am using useRef to pass the reference of the div element to my function, but I am getting an error while passing the argument.

```
const Home = () => {
    const divRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const x = DivPosition(divRef);

    return (
        ...
    )
}
```

my DivPosition.tsx code:

```
interface IDivPosition{
    divRef: HTMLDivElement | null
}

export const DivPosition = ({divRef}: IDivPosition) => {

  useEffect(() => {
      console.log(divRef);
  });
    ...
  return x;
};
```

I am getting an error saying:
Argument of type 'RefObject' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IDivPosition'.
Property 'divRef' is missing in type 'RefObject' but required in type 'IDivPosition'

Comment: Show the code of `useMousePosition` hook.

Comment: sorry I named it wrong in the question. Its actually a "DivPosition"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return value of `useRef` is `RefObject`, type definition

```
/*
* convenience overload for refs given as a ref prop as they typically start with a null value
*
* Usage note: if you need the result of useRef to be directly mutable, include `| null` in the type
* of the generic argument.
* @version 16.8.0
* @see https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref
*/
function useRef<T>(initialValue: T|null): RefObject<T>;
```

try:

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

interface IDivPosition {
  divRef: RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;
}

export const useDivPosition = ({ divRef }: IDivPosition) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(divRef);
  });
  return null;
};

const Home = () => {
  const divRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const x = useDivPosition({ divRef });

  return null;
};
```

package versions:

```json
"react": "^16.14.0",
"@types/react": "^16.14.14",
"typescript": "^4.4.2"
```

Besides, please name the custom hooks starting with "use".

> **Do I have to name my custom Hooks starting with “use”?** Please do. This convention is very important. Without it, we wouldn’t be able to automatically check for violations of rules of Hooks because we couldn’t tell if a certain function contains calls to Hooks inside of it.

Comment: That's not correct. A ref for an element type `T` which is managed by React and initialized with `null` is `RefObject<T>`. Check the source to verify: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/caad3f0aabaad827e6beaa3290b82c3bbe1f58b7/types/react/index.d.ts#L1028-L1066

Comment: Now getting Error:
```
Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement | null>' is not assignable to type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLDivElement>'.
  Type 'HTMLDivElement | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLDivElement'.
    Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLDivElement'.
```

Comment: @jsejcksn Yes, you are correct, update the answer

Comment: the updated one fixed my issue